# How do you convert a transformation function to matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say you have $$T(x,\,y) = (x+iy,\,y+ix)$$

How do I convert that to a matrix?

Comment: Don't know who is formulating the question, but it is badly designed: the most obvious wrong approach (transposing the matrix) will give the _same_ result, so one cannot tell from the answer if the proper method was applied. A better question would be to for instance ask about $(x,y)\mapsto(x+iy,y-ix)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T:V\to W$ is a linear transformation and $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$ knowing the images of $v_1$, $v_2$, $\ldots,v_n$ under $T$ we can get the asked matrix.
So, as $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ is a basis of $V_2$ we have $T(1,0)=\begin{bmatrix}1\\i\end{bmatrix}$ and $T(0,1)=\begin{bmatrix}i\\1\end{bmatrix}$, then
$$T(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}1 & i \\ i & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$$